# linux mint - android studio emulator process killed

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, linux-mint

I have just migrate to Mint from windows. I installed android studio v4. As I want to start the emulator, I got into error.
[image]

I'll be thank of who can give me a hand.

Comment: check your SDK and if your API is downloaded  properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friends help me. He sayed it was due to GPU. He changed the Graphic card.

Answer (score 1):

Add 32-bit support:
https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2211

Make sure you install all the dependencies needed by Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/studio/install

And `libvrt` for emulation:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt

After that, it should work properly. These instructions are valid for Ubuntu, but I think you can find similar packages for Linux Mint. Make sure you install the 32-bit packages (`a_package:i386`) when the links above require it. If it still doesn't work, try running Android Studio and the emulator from the command line (to see what goes wrong) and send a bug report to the Android Studio team.

Comment: tnx dear, unfortunately didn't helped.